conditional formatting on a single cell where criteria is another column [solved]
Cell A1 contains the text "FLAG".
Column B contains dates.
I want to apply conditional formatting to cell A1 if any date in column B is less than 2 days from today(), and if the date is past today().
An example of what I've tried:
Column B:
10/12/2024
11/12/2024
06/12/2024
Assuming today is 04/12/2024, conditional formatting applied to Cell A1:
=$B$1:$B>TODAY()+2

I would expect cell A1 to flag as it meets the criteria with date 06/12/2024.
=$B$1:$B>TODAY()+1

I wouldn't expect cell A1 to flag.
If I add the date 01/12/2024 to column B and remove 06/12/2024,
I would expect the cell A1 to flag with either of what I've tried.
Neither option has the desired result.
Thanks.

Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See How much research effort is expected of stackoverflow users?

Assuming today is 04/12/2024, A1 should get highlighted if and ONLY 05/12/24 and/or 06/12/24 are found in Column_B?!

Correct @rockinfreakshow, except 05/12/24 is not in my list of example dates, but if it were, then yes, A1 would be highlighted.


Custom formula is:
=+sort(xmatch({today()+1;today()+2},B:B))



Thanks @rockinfreakshow. I've never seen '+sort' after a "=" before - what does this do?

its just a shortcut to restrict the array/range to top first value; something akin to using index(<array>,1,1)

Or more traditionally, custom formula:
=countifs(B:B,">="&today()+1,B:B,"<="&today()+2)

or
=countif(B:B,today()+1)+countif(B:B,today()+2)


You may use this alternative custom formula:
=REDUCE(FALSE,ARRAYFORMULA((TO_DATE(B1:B)<=(TODAY()+2))*(TO_DATE(B1:B)>=(TODAY()+1))), LAMBDA(a,c, a+c))

Sample Output:

Reference:

REDUCE function


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.  Also note that the question is ONLY if there's a date  between TODAY()+1 and TODAY()+2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79251258/conditional-formatting-on-a-single-cell-where-criteria-is-another-column-solved#comment139749755_79251258

@TheMaster Thank you for the feedback. I posted the picture to demonstrate the output with highlighting, as this is challenging to convey using a Markdown table, particularly for colored cells or highlighted columns. I also updated my custom formula.

Do we need to demonstrate it works, for every answer? I mean I understand - if it works for one, but not for others - then you need to demonstrate - that there's an issue or that itworks on your end.. but it's just conditional formatting
